What is 擦边 as in the case of the athlete champion turned dancer？
If you follow China news closely, you may notice the heated debate about a retired and former world champion woman gymnastic athlete 吴柳芳 who livestreamed her sexy dance on tiktok social media and the buzzword 擦边 the livestream brought alive. She was condemned for her 擦边 behavior.
I tried to contact some of the comment writers who used the word for definition and clarity, but without getting any effective response.
So what is 擦边?

It originates from the term 擦边球 in table tennis.
As stated in the link, 打擦边球 becomes a metaphor for doing something near the boundaries of what is acceptable, i.e., in a legal or moral gray area. While 打擦边球 is used in a general context, people now use 擦边 specifically for the behavior of producing sexy materials but not to the extent of being considered sexual content and getting censored.

說希望別人去死是違反微信規則，那麼說希望別人下場悲慘是不是擦邊球呢？

"擦边" is originally from ball sports with border, which means you've hit the border line, but you're still will be judged as within the valid boundary. Such as "擦边球" in table tennis indicate the ball hit the edge of the table, which normally makes it difficult for opponent to react.
Yet, although it normally means good point in sports, the effective of the danger or risk of been almost out of boundary has been borrowed here, in context of talking with context of "legal boundary" or "moral boundary".
As you might know that sex content in public is out of the legal and moral boundary in China, "擦边" here means publish semi-sex content to attract audience.

擦边：游走在法律的边缘。
说违法吧，也没有明确的违法事实。说不违法吧，吴柳芳直播跳舞的时候穿的有点裸露。

This is a hot topic，the 边 means boundary， 擦边 means someone are acting near the valid or reason area. 擦 means slighty touch.
It is a word used in many context to accuse someone is in debating area.
In the question context， 擦边  means she posts some videos between the porn and ordinary video.
At the moment of answering this question, the government says: Living is more important.
So her account is in normal status.
You can't say sexy is porn  right?

China should follow the trend of the world. In the US, Japan, Thailand, the Netherland and other European countries porn is a legal business that has driven up the total economy.
